# How come "Dilwale Dulhania Le Jayenge" survives?

Tags: distribution, indian-cinema, dilwale-dulhania-le-jayenge

I have 2 questions to ask.

Considering the tough market in Bollywood distribution of movies. How come [*Dilwale Dulhania Le Jayenge* (DDLJ)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilwale_Dulhania_Le_Jayenge) crossed 1000 weeks. I feel there are many other love stories in Bollywood. Why only DDLJ? Is Maratha Mandir doing business still now?

Is there any other movie like DDLJ which comes even close to surviving this many weeks all over the world?

Comment: And it will be keep going this way, Maratha Mandir took decision to continue this.

Comment: Anyways better keep 2 question separately. Keeping 2 question inside one will keep attract partial answers.

Comment: It is funded by its producers.

Answer (score 9):

I think DDLJ crossed 1000 weeks in maratha mandir because it does not affect much of it's business because it only runs in time slot of 11:30 AM.

Yes,  Maratha Mandir doing business. Maratha Mandir not only plays DDLJ. It also plays regular releases.

Answer to your second question is probably no. No other movie ran for so much long time in theatre. I think another movie which comes to second place after DDLJ in terms of longest theatrical run is Sholay which ran for 286 weeks.

Answer (score 4):

Dilwale Dulhania Le Jayenge or DDLJ is the most successful Bollywood love story ever made. It gives us the Sharukh/Kajol Duo. Even after it they both acted as couple due to audience demand followed by Kuch Kuch hota hai, Kabhi Khushi Kabhi Gum etc.

At the time it was released, it made too many new records and broke old ones. This made it unforgettable.

Why it broke record because people loved it, as vj1207 said, Maratha Mandir is doing good business and it also shows other films too. DDLJ only hold one show slot and is still showing.

It also got support from Yash Raj Camp too.

> In early 2011, a theatre strike threatened the film's uninterrupted showing streak. Producer Yash Chopra contacted theatre owners to try and ensure that the film would continue. He hoped that the film would continue to run for at least 1000 weeks. - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilwale_Dulhania_Le_Jayenge#Legacy)

It's also famous for [Jokes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8942/why-didnt-simran-get-into-bogey-from-first-door-in-ddlj) too but it's commonly used scene in recent flicks and TV shows too as homage.